# Why a "single variable model" overperforms a multivariate model for classification?

Tags: roc

I have a dataset with 2 possible outcomes, disease vs healthy, when looking for biomarkers there is one variable that yields ahigher AUROC than a model built with 5 variables including that same feature.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer your question without more information about the data and model you're using.

Generally speaking, making a model more complex (e.g. by adding additional predictors) increases the risk of **overfitting** to the training data, which can lead to bad performance on the test data.

Another possible reason for decreasing predictive performance when adding additional predictors is **multicollinearity** between the predictors. You can check this by looking at the *correlations between them* or, in regression models, at *variance inflation factors*.